# How To Pass An Array Of String To A Web Service In WCF Which Has Been Consumed By Java Application?

Tags: web-services, wcf

`UpdateConsumerData` is the API which is exposed to Java client.

```
public void UpdateConsumerData(CustomerData customerData)
{

    /* code here */
}

[DataContract]
public class CustomerData
{

    List<string> name = null;
    List<string> id = null;

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Id
    {

        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
}
```

This API generates WSDL and XSD as below

```
<xs:complexType name="CustomerData">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name" 
                type="q1:ArrayOfstring" 
                minOccurs="0" 
                nillable="true"
                 xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
    <xs:element name="Id" 
                type="q2:ArrayOfstring" 
                minOccurs="0" 
                nillable="true"
               xmlns:q2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

It's generating element type as type="q1:ArrayOfstring" where as it should be type="xsd:string"

What code changes we require to do in `CustomerData` to generate desired XSD and WSDL?

Comment: but the `DataMember`s of the `DataContract` are clearly collections, not `string`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays instead of collections. The collection types do not translate very well over SOAP, but array types do quite well.

Comment: both are giving same result.

Comment: svcutil generates ArrayOfStrings